# using scanf("%[^\n]") and saving it to int type. (I get different output on different platforms.)

Tags: c

*This is the code I am using.*

I wanna know why I am getting this kinda output moreover different output in online compiler and macOS.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int variable;
    printf("Enter\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",&variable);
    printf("char = %c\n",variable);
    printf("int = %d\n",variable);
    return 0;
}
```

**online C compiler replit.com**
[image: online C compiler replit.com]
**macOS terminal**
[image: macOS terminal]

Comment: Undefined behaviour leads to different results on different machines, and both are equally correct.  You can't read a string into a pointer to integer reliably.

Comment: I am voting to close as typo/thinko/UB.